# How to create tabs using Javascript and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do you make multiple tabs on a page? For example, you click the buttons on the menu and a page slides in. The url does not change in the process. Is there a way to do this with jquery, javascript? I have the html and css.

```css
div.tabContent.hide {
  display: none;
}
nav {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
nav ul {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
}
li a {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333333;
  border-radius: 0px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}
li a:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 8px -6px #333;
  color: #222222;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul id="tabs">
    <li>
      <a href="#home" style="font-weight: bold;">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#products" style="font-weight: bold;">Products</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#order" style="font-weight: bold;">Order</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#settings" style="font-weight: bold;">Settings</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: you mean you want like tabs or something like that?

Comment: This can be done in countless ways. It sounds like you want to build a [Single-page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) or "SPA". If you want to build a front-end application, I'd recommend ditching the jQuery training wheels and pick up a real front-end library like [React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) or something

Comment: @Ben Yes. Exactly. So the url doesn't change.

Comment: okay i will add the code using Jquery

Comment: @naomik Yes. Can you do it with those languages?

Comment: @Akidus I didn't mention any languages.

Comment: @naomik the ones I mentioned.

Comment: @Ben Can it be with a slide in animation? I am still learning Jquery.

Comment: you want a animated gif you mean?

Comment: Sort of. I have seen jquery slide-in animations.

Comment: @Akidus React is written in JavaScript, so yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
   <head>
  <!-- This page is copyright Elated Communications Ltd. (www.elated.com) -->

    <title>JavaScript tabs example</title>

  <style type="text/css">
   body { font-size: 80%; font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, Sans- Serif; }
   ul#tabs { list-style-type: none; margin: 30px 0 0 0; padding: 0 0 0.3em 0;       }
   ul#tabs li { display: inline; }
   ul#tabs li a { color: #42454a; background-color: #dedbde; border: 1px  solid #c9c3ba; border-bottom: none; padding: 0.3em; text-decoration: none; }
   ul#tabs li a:hover { background-color: #f1f0ee; }
   ul#tabs li a.selected { color: #000; background-color: #f1f0ee; font-  weight: bold; padding: 0.7em 0.3em 0.38em 0.3em; }
   div.tabContent { border: 1px solid #c9c3ba; padding: 0.5em; background-  color: #f1f0ee; }
  div.tabContent.hide { display: none; }
 </style>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[

 var tabLinks = new Array();
 var contentDivs = new Array();

 function init() {

  // Grab the tab links and content divs from the page
  var tabListItems = document.getElementById('tabs').childNodes;
  for ( var i = 0; i < tabListItems.length; i++ ) {
    if ( tabListItems[i].nodeName == "LI" ) {
      var tabLink = getFirstChildWithTagName( tabListItems[i], 'A' );
      var id = getHash( tabLink.getAttribute('href') );
      tabLinks[id] = tabLink;
      contentDivs[id] = document.getElementById( id );
    }
  }

  // Assign onclick events to the tab links, and
  // highlight the first tab
  var i = 0;

  for ( var id in tabLinks ) {
    tabLinks[id].onclick = showTab;
    tabLinks[id].onfocus = function() { this.blur() };
    if ( i == 0 ) tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
    i++;
  }

  // Hide all content divs except the first
  var i = 0;

  for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
    if ( i != 0 ) contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
    i++;
  }
 }

  function showTab() {
   var selectedId = getHash( this.getAttribute('href') );

   // Highlight the selected tab, and dim all others.
   // Also show the selected content div, and hide all others.
   for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
    if ( id == selectedId ) {
      tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
      contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent';
    } else {
      tabLinks[id].className = '';
      contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
    }
  }

  // Stop the browser following the link
  return false;
   }

   function getFirstChildWithTagName( element, tagName ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++ ) {
     if ( element.childNodes[i].nodeName == tagName ) return element.childNodes[i];
    }
   }

 function getHash( url ) {
   var hashPos = url.lastIndexOf ( '#' );
   return url.substring( hashPos + 1 );
 }

 //]]>
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="init()">
  <h1>JavaScript tabs example</h1>

   <ul id="tabs">
  <li><a href="#about">About JavaScript tabs</a></li>
  <li><a href="#advantages">Advantages of tabs</a></li>
  <li><a href="#usage">Using tabs</a></li>
   </ul>

    <div class="tabContent" id="about">
    <h2>About JavaScript tabs</h2>
    <div>
    <p>JavaScript tabs partition your Web page content into tabbed sections.  Only one section at a time is visible.</p>
    <p>The code is written in such a way that the page degrades gracefully  in browsers that don't support JavaScript or CSS.</p>
   </div>
   </div>

   <div class="tabContent" id="advantages">
   <h2>Advantages of tabs</h2>
   <div>
    <p>JavaScript tabs are great if your Web page contains a large amount of content.</p>
    <p>They're also good for things like multi-step Web forms.</p>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tabContent" id="usage">
  <h2>Using tabs</h2>
  <div>
    <p>Click a tab to view the tab's content. Using tabs couldn't be easier!   </p>
  </div>
  </div>


 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: For me when I tried it, it showed all tabs. The links didn't do anything.

Comment: Wierd. Maybe you have files I don't.

Comment: No. It shows all the files and the url changes on the links.

Comment: A lot better. Thanks!

Comment: you want something that fades in?

Comment: when you click on the tab

Comment: Yes, but it would be better if they slide in.